# How to Delete a File from a folder using PHP

Tags: php, image

I am currently developing a IMAGE GALLERY site. Every thing is working well and GOOD except a small Problem. For example, if i am deleting a image in the site its deleting successfully from the database and no longer displaying in the gallery. But i need to remove the specific image from  the folder. Is there any chance to do that. if YES please guide me to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete a file you need to use the [`unlink()`](http://php.net/unlink) function.

Comment: hi greg.. one more guidance.. will you please let me know how to answer for the questions posted by the user.

Comment: this is my first day in stackoverflow.. i search for it but there is nothing related to Your Answer. Is there any other option

Comment: Do you want to post an answer to your own question or to another users question.

Comment: @Fero - unlink does exactly what you are looking for, why would you want another option?

Comment: If you need to post an answer to another user's question then open the corresponding question page and at the bottom there is a textarea [actually a markdown editor] for entering your answer.

Comment: If you need to answer your own question then there is a button at the bottom named Answer Your Question.

Comment: yes karim.  unlink is the correct option what i search for.. thanks for ur advice too..

Answer (score 0):

[PHP : Delete a file, or a folder and its contents](http://putraworks.wordpress.com/2006/02/27/php-delete-a-file-or-a-folder-and-its-contents/)